# dataframe reshaping with new added columns

Tags: python, pandas

```
columns = ['a', "b","cin",'cout', 'din', 'dout']
rows = [[1 , 1, 3, 4, 2, 3], [2,3,3,1, 8 , 4], [3,1,3,1, 2, 1]]
dff1 = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=columns)
```

**result**

[image]

How to make the output as 6 rows where Cin,Cout and din,dout are taken as 2 sperate rows with a and b ? Also with an added column in/out.

In general, I need to manipulate the above dataframe to bring the below attached

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lreshape`:

```
df = pd.lreshape(dff, {'c':['c1','c2'], 'd':['d1','d2']})
print (df)
   a  b  c  d
0  1  1  3  2
1  2  3  3  8
2  3  1  3  2
3  1  1  4  3
4  2  3  1  4
5  3  1  1  1
```

Or [`wide_to_long`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.wide_to_long.html):

```
dff = dff.reset_index()
a = (pd.wide_to_long(dff, stubnames=['c', 'd'], i='index', j='B')
       .reset_index(drop=True)
       .reindex(columns=['a','b','c', 'd']))
print (a)
   a  b  c  d
0  1  1  3  2
1  2  3  3  8
2  3  1  3  2
3  1  1  4  3
4  2  3  1  4
5  3  1  1  1
```

EDIT: If want also columns use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html), [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and last [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
a = dff1.melt(id_vars=['a','b'],value_vars=['cin','cout'],value_name = 'c',var_name='in/out')
b = dff1.melt(id_vars=['a','b'],value_vars=['din','dout'],value_name = 'd',var_name='in/out')
a['in/out'] = a['in/out'].str.extract('(in|out)', expand=False)
b['in/out'] = b['in/out'].str.extract('(in|out)', expand=False)
print (a)
   a  b in/out  c
0  1  1     in  3
1  2  3     in  3
2  3  1     in  3
3  1  1    out  4
4  2  3    out  1
5  3  1    out  1

print (b)
   a  b in/out  d
0  1  1     in  2
1  2  3     in  8
2  3  1     in  2
3  1  1    out  3
4  2  3    out  4
5  3  1    out  1

c = a.assign(d=b['d']).sort_values(['a','b'])
#same as
#c = pd.merge(a,b).sort_values(['a','b'])

print (c)
   a  b in/out  c  d
0  1  1     in  3  2
3  1  1    out  4  3
1  2  3     in  3  8
4  2  3    out  1  4
2  3  1     in  3  2
5  3  1    out  1  1
```

Solution rewritten for `pandas 0.15.0`:

```
a=pd.melt(dff1,id_vars=['a','b'],value_vars=['cin','cout'],value_name='c',var_name='in/out') 
b=pd.melt(dff1,id_vars=['a','b'],value_vars=['din','dout'],value_name='d',var_name='in/out')
a['in/out'] = a['in/out'].str.extract('(in|out)')
b['in/out'] = b['in/out'].str.extract('(in|out)')
c = pd.merge(a,b).sort_values(['a','b'])
```

Another solution from wen's deleted answer - is necessary [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) strings to numeric and then use [`wide_to_long`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.wide_to_long.html), last [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) back:

```
#define columns
L = ['in','out']
d = dict(enumerate(L))
d1 = {v: str(k) for k, v in d.items()}
print (d)
{0: 'in', 1: 'out'}

print (d1)
{'out': '1', 'in': '0'}

dff1.columns = dff1.columns.to_series().replace(d1,regex=True)
a = pd.wide_to_long(dff1, stubnames=['c', 'd'], j='in/out', i=['a','b']).reset_index()
a['in/out'] = a['in/out'].astype(int).map(d)
a = a[['a','b','c','d','in/out']]
print (a)
   a  b  c  d in/out
0  1  1  3  2     in
1  1  1  4  3    out
2  2  3  3  8     in
3  2  3  1  4    out
4  3  1  3  2     in
5  3  1  1  1    out
```

EDIT:

For revert process use:

```
df = df.set_index(['a', 'b', 'in/out']).unstack()
df.columns = df.columns.map(''.join)
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
   a  b  cin  cout  din  dout
0  1  1    3     4    2     3
1  2  3    3     1    8     4
2  3  1    3     1    2     1
```

Comment: Thanks, when reshaping, is it also possible to tag each row with the another column added with values from the names of the column. For example, if the column names were [a,b,cin,cout,din,dout]. while reshaping I would need to specify which row is in and out

Comment: Thanks, but I am in another problem. I am using pandas 0.15 and when I edit your code a bit for that, I am getting str_extract() got an unexpected argument 'expand'   a = pd.melt(dff1, id_vars=['a','b'], value_vars=['cin','cout'], value_name='c', var_name='in/out')
b = pd.melt(dff1, id_vars=['a','b'], value_vars=['din','dout'], value_name='d', var_name='in/out')

Comment: Nope.. It is not possible in my project.

Comment: But the error is "an unexpected keyword argument 'expand'"

Comment: damn, now it goes to AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'assign'. Also tried pd.assign but assign is not available there

Comment: Thanks it worked Could you please edit the heading according to this problem ?

Comment: @Wen - Is not problem for added your solution to my answer?

Comment: @Yogi - Done, I am really happy ;)

Comment: Could you please also add to your answer, how to revert back to old dataframe model ?